# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: java, loops

When ever I run this program I got problem on its final stage. I can't print the value of t[5]. can anybody help me out from this issue?
I want to take t[n] values upto n = NoL but program run without error till I enter the final value. (I call this method to main method. and get a problem like image 1 [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTQsh.jpg)

```
    for(n=1; n<=NoL; n++){  
    if (n==1){
            System.out.println("your 1st letter in which column?");
            t[n] = input.nextInt();
        }
    else if (n==2){
            System.out.println("your 2nd letter in which column?");
            t[n] = input.nextInt();

        }
    else if (n==3){
            System.out.println("your 3rd letter in which column?");
            t[n] = input.nextInt();

        }
    else{  
        for (n=4; n<=NoL ; n++){                
                System.out.println("your "+  n+"th letter in which column?");
                t[n] = input.nextInt();
            }

        }
    }   
System.out.println(t[3]);
}
```

What should I do now? Please help me thanks in advance....

Comment: Please add a more descriptive title... also try debugging the program before asking the question.

Comment: `I can't print the value of t[5]` ... this is because you never print it.  As a general comment, arrays in Java (and most languages) are zero based, meaning your loop should start at index zero, not one.

Comment: Thanks for your time... I'll add is asap

Comment: What is `t.length`? The maximum index in the array will be `t.length - 1`

Comment: Hint: what is definitely wrong: variable names go camelCase; so *NoL* is violating java naming conventions. It is also a bad name in the sense that such abbreviations only "save on typing"; but lead to massive loss in readability. Then: int counters are typically called i, j, k, ... so using *n* is a bit confusing, too.

Answer (score 0):

If N = 4 then you are entering a second for loop.
So when N = 5 you enter the last part of the if-else statement and set N back to 4 again. Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but probably don't need the second for loop.